# Getting laser scan intensity values from RVIZ

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, 2dlidar, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get intensity values being returned via the `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` message. I am using RViz to visualize this data and I found that the display RGB value is being computed off the intensities being returned from this link:
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/LaserScan

I am trying to get the intensities returned in a specific part of the laser scan. I was wondering if there was a way to get that from the RViz visualization (where I already see the RGB points)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372430/getting-laser-scan-intensity-values-from-rviz/) by [ymanian](https://answers.ros.org/users/70626/ymanian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get the information I needed using the select tool from RVIZ. I was able to publish this information using the `selected_points_publisher` found here: https://github.com/tu-rbo/turbo-ros-pkg/tree/master/selected_points_publisher

---

Originally posted by [ymanian](https://answers.ros.org/users/70626/ymanian/) with karma: 36 on 2021-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1